# Add new element to dictionary below key-level python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling with including an element to my dictionary. The dictionary has two keys, namely *h* and *a*. This is clearly visible if I use the following code:

```
  shots = driver.execute_script("return shotsData")
  for x in shots:
    print(x)
```

However, if I loop through the dictionary with the following code

```
shots = driver.execute_script("return shotsData")
for x in shots:
   print(shots[x])
```

I see the following output:

```html
[
{
  'X': '0.7909999847412109',
  'Y': '0.36700000762939455',
  'a_goals': '1',
  'a_team': 'Manchester City',
  'date': '2015-12-22 00:00:00',
  'h_a': 'a',
  'h_goals': '2',
  'h_team': 'Arsenal',
  'id': '55522',
  'lastAction': 'Pass',
  'match_id': '250',
  'minute': '6',
  'player': 'David Silva',
  'player_assisted': 'Bacary Sagna',
  'player_id': '617',
  'result': 'MissedShots',
  'season': '2015',
  'shotType': 'LeftFoot',
  'situation': 'OpenPlay',
  'xG': '0.02694704197347164'
},
...
]
```

The output represents data about each shot that was taken during a soccer match. So, the *shots*-variable is a dictionary that consists of all the shots of home-(away) team where *a* and *h* represent the actual team.

I want to include the league of the match. However, using the following code

```
league = 'premier_league'
shots.update({'league': league})
```

gives me *a, h, league* instead of

```html
{
  'X': '0.7909999847412109',
  'Y': '0.36700000762939455',
  'a_goals': '1',
  'a_team': 'Manchester City',
  'date': '2015-12-22 00:00:00',
  'h_a': 'a',
  'h_goals': '2',
  'h_team': 'Arsenal',
  'id': '55522',
  'lastAction': 'Pass',
  'match_id': '250',
  'minute': '6',
  'player': 'David Silva',
  'player_assisted': 'Bacary Sagna',
  'player_id': '617',
  'result': 'MissedShots',
  'season': '2015',
  'shotType': 'LeftFoot',
  'situation': 'OpenPlay',
  'xG': '0.02694704197347164',
  'League': 'premier_league', 
},
```

How should I change my code? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where _do_ you want to add the `'league'` key: to the dictionary which contains multiple dictionaries that represent the games or to each of the latter dictionaries? Right now you're adding it to the 'outer' dictionary

Comment: each of the latter dictionaries!

Comment: why are you adding it to the outer dictionary then? Loop over all the inner ones and append the data to them, like in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code

```
league = 'premier_league'
shots.update({'league': league})
```

with the below code

```
league = 'premier_league'
for shot in shots:
    for d in shots[shot]:
        d.update({'league': league})
```

Comment: Your solution yields the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: can you paste the result of print(shots)

Comment: for shot in shots:
       print(shot)

yiels

a
h
The output of print(shots) is too long to comment here

Comment: can you share the output of print(shots) by editing the question

Comment: {
  'a': [
    {
      'X': '0.79',
      'Y': '0.35',
      'a_goals': '1',
      'a_team': 'Manchester City',
      'date': '2015-12-22 00:00:00',
      'h_a': 'a',
      'h_goals': '2',
      'h_team': 'Arsenal',
      'id': '55522',
      'lastAction': 'Pass',
      'match_id': '250',
      'minute': '6',
      'player': 'David Silva',
      'player_assisted': 'Bacary Sagna',
      'player_id': '617',
      'result': 'MissedShots',
      'season': '2015',
      'shotType': 'LeftFoot',
      'situation': 'OpenPlay',
      'xG': '0.024'
    },
etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186967/discussion-between-kannappan-sirchabesan-and-hja24).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `shots` is a dictionary of a list of dictionaries. You need to update each "shot sub-dictionary".

The easiest way to do this, is to iterate over the shots, and then setting the 'league' key in the shot:

```
league = 'premier_league'
for team_shots in shots.values():
    for shot in team_shots:
        shot['league'] = league
```